# How to delete network namespace, no pids option available for ip netns

Tags: ip, network-namespaces

How to clean up network namespace, CentOS 6.5 does not have `ip netns pids` option, so can't use `ip netns pids ns-2001 | xargs kill`

```
ip netns list | grep ns-2001
ns-2001

ip netns pids ns-2001 | xargs kill
Command "pids" is unknown, try "ip netns help".
usage: kill [ -s signal | -p ] [ -a ] pid ...
kill -l [ signal ]

sudo ip netns delete ns-2001
Cannot remove /var/run/netns/ns-2001: Device or resource busy

ip netns help
Usage: ip netns list
       ip netns add NAME
       ip netns delete NAME
       ip netns exec NAME cmd ...
       ip netns monitor
```

Comment: but still the command should have allowed to "remove" ns-2001 without an error, even if processes are still using the namespace (and even if a process has opened the mount point: the umount is done with  MNT_DETACH). **Also**, centos 6.5 (or 6.10)'s iproute package doesn't support ip netns at all, so I'm wondering where does this command come from.

Comment: nailed it down to be probably related to this commit: [iproute2: Make "ip netns delete" more likely to succeed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/commit/?id=58a3e8270fe72f8ed92687d3a3132c2a708582dd). So wherever you got the iproute package, get an updated version...